# A camera for crime investigation

Tags: production-technology

Technically, is it possible to produce a camera that would allow the investigator to video record the entire criminal process on site a few months later after it took place?

I am not talking here about time travel, considered a fantasy by the general public.

I'm talking about letting the investigator stay in the present time, using a camera to film the past event, a technology that requires a major advance in science and concepts to achieve.

Comment: possibly `yes` ...  time travel technology is probably possible, just not for our civilization ...

Comment: I hate the idea of time travel, instead I prefer the investigator to stay in the present while using a camera to film the past event rather than physically traveling back in time, which is much more difficult.

Comment: your question belongs in the fantasy realm

Comment: Without fantasy, human beings will never be able to land on the moon.

Answer (score 1):

No. the light given off by the acts involving a months-old crime are long gone and cannot be collected together again to make pictures.

Comment: Future breakthroughs and discoveries in physics will provide new clue to this problem. I believe nothing is impossible.

Comment: And we are back to time travel....

Comment: I don't agree with your thinking. Collecting images of past events does not mean we have to travel back in time.

Comment: to capture any light at all from an event in the past would require you to travel faster than light so you could catch up with it. This is impossible and the reason why is woven deep into the structure of the universe we inhabit- so deeply that there's nothing we can do about it.